# Inject generic interface in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to inject this interface to my controllers:

```
public interface IDatabaseService<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetList();
    ...
}
```

I want to use generic, because in my `WebApi` project i have controllers like `ProjectController`, `TaskController` etc and i want to use generic interface to each of type (for example, `IDatabaseService<Project>`, `IdatabaseService<Task>` etc).

Class, that will be injected to controller will look like this:

```
public class ProjectService : IDatabaseService<Project>
{
    private readonly DbContext context;

    public ProjectService(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Project> GetList() { }
    ...
}
```

But when I try to ineject in my `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseService<T>>();
```

I need to pass `T` type.

My question is, how to make injection generic and how inject it properly in controller? For example:

```
public class ProjectController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ProjectService projectService;

    public ProjectController (IDatabaseService<Project> projectService)
    {
        this.projectService = projectService;
    }
}
```

If it will work? And is it good practice to make generic interface to inject into controllers? If no, how to do it better?

Comment: You should be able to do `services.AddScoped(typeof(IDatabaseService<>));`

Comment: Another question is my thinking have sense? What is the best practice in scenerio that i explained in my question?

Comment: And if it enough to inject classes like `ProjectService` to my controllers?

Comment: What is the benefit of `ProjectService` and `IDatabaseService` when it's only a thin layer wrapping your `DbContext`? Use your `DbContext` directly and use its In-Memory provider for testing scenarios.

Comment: I wanted to work only on `DbSet` with `Projects` in my mind, so how it work in "real life" scenerios? Its better to deal with one `IDatabaseService` and `DatabaseService` if each one controller? I think `ProjectController` dont need to have (for example) reference to `Tasks`

Comment: @Izzy Should but get this when trying: `Cannot instantiate implementation type 'IDatabaseService`1[T]' for service type 'IDatabaseService`1[T]'.`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1.) if you want to write hard code

```
services.AddScoped<IDatabaseService<Project>, ProjectService>();
```

2.) if you want to register dynamically that all types of implemented `IDatabaseService<>`

```
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(item => item.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(i => i.IsGenericType).Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDatabaseService<>)) && !item.IsAbstract && !item.IsInterface)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(assignedTypes =>
            {
                var serviceType = assignedTypes.GetInterfaces().First(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDatabaseService<>));
                services.AddScoped(serviceType, assignedTypes);
            });
```

Comment: Could you provide more complex explenation about second paragraph?

Comment: If you have a large number of services that implement the IDatabaseService<> interface, it provides to find and register all of them.

Comment: Is the use of reflection then iterating over all service types to `AddScoped` a one time cost at application startup? My hunch says yes, but just want to confirm.

Comment: @JethroCao: yes it is as the container is built once at startup.

Answer (score 82):

You can do this by adding the below line in `Startup.cs`

```
// best practice  
services.AddTransient(typeof(IDatabaseService<>),typeof(DatabaseService<>));
```

Visit [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to know more about **Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core**

Comment: `services.AddTransient<IDatabaseService<T>, DatabaseService<T>>();` this isnt going to work with a generic type, you'd have to add the concrete type instead of T. When using generic parameters, they must be known at compile time. Second line is the only way to register it w/o knowing and defining the concrete type(s) (per type registration)

Comment: I wanted to work only on `DbSet` with `Projects` in my mind, so how it work in "real life" scenerios? Its better to deal with one `IDatabaseService` and `DatabaseService` if each one controller? I think `ProjectController` dont need to have (for example) reference to `Tasks`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have removed the wrong example.

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in my quesion, i wan to have classes like `TaskService : IDatabaseService<Task>` and `ProjectService : IDatabaseService<Project>`. I dobt have 'DatabaseService' class

Comment: How do you then make the declaration in the constructor without having to specify a specific type?

Answer (score 24):

You can use services.AddScoped to use only 1 instance in the scope request. So in general improvement compare to AddTransient

```cs
services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

So my interface and class will look like this

```cs
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

```cs
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

Comment: Such as this use case, how we handle?

public class GenericRepository<T, U> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class where U class

I tried below code but runtime error

services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<,>));

Comment: You can read my blog for full source code https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/generic-repository-pattern-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to use helpers:

**by Generic interface**

```
services.AddAllGenericTypes(typeof(IDatabaseService<>), new[] {typeof(ProjectService).GetTypeInfo().Assembly});
```

With extensions from:
https://gist.github.com/GetoXs/5caf0d8cfe6faa8a855c3ccef7c5a541

Comment: Can Scrutor do this? https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor