# super class constraints to verify if the subclass has an implementation of an interface

Tags: .net, constraints

How can i create a constraint class that test if the class that get extended has a sub class that implements an interface?

I need to do this with the super class:

`public abstract class ConsumerHandler where SubClass : IConsumer<any>`

and in the SubClass:

`public class NewProductConsumerHandler : ConsumerHandler, IConsumer<NewProduct>`

if i create the subclass like this, it shouldnt let me use it:

`public class NewProductConsumerHandler : ConsumerHandler`

Comment: I suggest to tag your question with the desired language. It _looks_ like c#, but you use java terminology. And I don't think such a constraint is possilbe in c#. Your first line isn't valid. As starting point I'd make it `public abstract class ConsumerHandler<T> : IConsumer<T>`, and declare abstract methods for the interface implementation. So derviced class automatically have to implement them. But the type constraint would not exactly meet your requirements.

Comment: The language is C# sorry haha, i've tagged only .net tag, the first line i wrote to be like a example to get what i was trying to code.

I was doind what you've said, and came this question in my mind if it is possible to do a constraint for this case. So i have to make the abstract class implement the interface.

Comment: In my configuration service i have this

``service.AddScoped<NewProductConsumerHandler>();``
``service.AddScoped<NewSaleConsumerHandler>()``

and i was trying to do that to remove the repetitition of this line and do only the

``services.AddScoped(typeof(ConsumerHandler));``

Comment: You might find lots of ideas in the [answers to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56143613/3791245).